# Reversing a number with 0s in the last position in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I've got this simple code for reversing integers. But I need to reverse numbers with leadings 0s now for another project. For example, this program is able to convert 32 to 23, but it converts 3200 to 23 as well. I need the 0s to stay in the leading place. However I've seen the binary operations on a bit level that can do this job, I'm looking for a way(if any) to do it without using bitwise operations and keeping it simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, mod = 0, reverse = 0;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    while(a!=0)
    {
       mod=a%10;
       reverse = reverse * 10 + mod;
       a=a/10;
    }
       printf("%d", reverse);
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can either modify `printf` to print leading zeroes, or instead try imaging the user inputs a string and instead reverse that.

Comment: 23 and 0023 is the same integer. If you need to distinguish between 23 and 0023, you are not dealing with integers any more and you need some data type other than `int`.

Comment: Convert your number to a string first, then reverse the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record the scan offset with `"%n"` when reading the integer.

Use the text width of the number to control the reversal and printing.

```
int main() {
  int a, mod = 0, reverse = 0;
  printf("Enter a number:");
  int n1, n2;
  scanf(" %n%d%n", &n1, &a, &n2);
  int width = n2 - n1;
  while (width-- > 0) {
    mod = a % 10;
    reverse = reverse * 10 + mod;
    a = a / 10;
  }
  printf("%0*d", n2-n1, reverse);
  return 0;
}
```

Example

```
Enter a number:00123
32100

Enter a number:12300
00321
```

---

Other considerations not handled.

- sign character `'+'` or `'-'`.
- Input outside `int` range
- Reversed number outside `int` range.
- Non-numeric input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should approach this problem as if the input where a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 15

void xor_swap(char *a, char *b) {
    if(a != b) {
        *a ^= *b;
        *b ^= *a;
        *a ^= *b;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buffer[MAX];
    size_t length;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    fgets(buffer, MAX, stdin);

    //fgets also includes the newline chracter so we get rid of that.
    length = strlen(buffer);
    buffer[length - 1] = '\0';
    length--;

    for(int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        xor_swap(&buffer[i], &buffer[length - i - 1]);
    }

    printf("buffer: %s\n", buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to take slightly different approach.
I would request somebody to do the code indentation for me as I am using cell phone to answer.

```
# define SIZE 10  
int main ()  
{  
int num= 3200;  
// keep one array of characters to store the reversed digits.  
char reversed_digit[SIZE];  
int i= 0, temp;  
if (num  == 0)  
    reversed_digit[i] = (char) num;  
else. 
{  
    while (num > 0)  
    {  
    temp= num % 10;  
    num= num / 10 ;  
    reversed_digit[i++]= (char) temp;  
    }  
    reversed_digit[i]= '\0';  
}
printf("The reversed digit is: %s ", reversed_digit);  
return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Note: with `num == 0`, `reversed_digit` becomes `""`.

Comment: @chux Thanks alot. Your suggedtion means alot. I have debugged the code kindly let me know if anything else need to be done.